# Alternative to Cross Apply in SQlite

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have a SQL query written for SQL Server but now I want to use it in SQLite.

###### Query

```
SELECT w.item_id,
       w.TotalStock,
       LastPartialStock.tranDate,
       LastPartialStock.StockToUse,
       LastPartialStock.RunningTotal,
       w.TotalStock - LastPartialStock.RunningTotal + LastPartialStock.StockToUse AS UseThisStock
FROM cteStockSum AS w CROSS APPLY (SELECT z.date as tranDate,
                                          z.ThisStock    AS StockToUse,
                                          z.RollingStock AS RunningTotal
                                                  FROM cteReverseInSum AS z
                                                  WHERE z.item_id = w.item_id
                                                    AND z.RollingStock >= w.TotalStock
                                                  ORDER BY z.date DESC LIMIT 1) AS LastPartialStock
```

But SQLite does not support `CROSS APPLY`, so I have to rewrite it.
One possible solution is to use subqueries for each column but that would result in not being able to use those column values as variables in the last column of the table i.e 'UseThisStock'.
Maybe I can use CTE but I am not able to figure this out.

**I tried this**

```
SELECT w.item_id,
       w.TotalStock,
       LastPartialStock.tranDate,
       LastPartialStock.StockToUse,
       LastPartialStock.RunningTotal,
       w.TotalStock - LastPartialStock.RunningTotal + LastPartialStock.StockToUse AS UseThisStock
FROM cteStockSum AS w , (SELECT z.date as tranDate,
                                          z.ThisStock    AS StockToUse,
                                          z.RollingStock AS RunningTotal
                                                  FROM cteReverseInSum AS z
                                                  WHERE z.item_id = w.item_id
                                                    AND z.RollingStock >= w.TotalStock
                                                  ORDER BY z.date DESC LIMIT 1) AS LastPartialStock
```

But the columns of `cteStockSum` are not recognized nor using any joins.

And the **performance** for this is critical as there would be 1 million rows and because this query is part of a complex query written with CTEs.

Comment: Does SQLite support LITERAL derived table?

Comment: @jarlh I think, it does not

Comment: Well, if this matter is so important, then where is an SQLite database fiddle populated with schema and sample data, desired output, and the entire query as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the subquery to your select clause in order to get the cteReverseInSum's `ROWID` (or something uniqely identifying a row within). Then use this ID in order to join the cteReverseInSum row.

```
SELECT
  ww.item_id,
  ww.TotalStock,
  LastPartialStock.tranDate,
  LastPartialStock.StockToUse,
  LastPartialStock.RunningTotal,
  ww.TotalStock - LastPartialStock.RunningTotal + LastPartialStock.StockToUse AS UseThisStock
FROM
  SELECT 
    w.*,
    (
      SELECT ROWID
      FROM cteReverseInSum AS z
      WHERE z.item_id = w.item_id
      AND z.RollingStock >= w.TotalStock
      ORDER BY z.date DESC
      LIMIT 1
    ) as z_rowid
  FROM cteStockSum AS w
) ww
JOIN cteReverseInSum AS LastPartialStock ON LastPartialStock.ROWID = ww.z_rowid;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your query returns 1 row for each `item_id` you could use an `INNER` join between the 2 ctes and aggregation:

```
SELECT s.item_id,
       s.TotalStock,
       MAX(r.date) tranDate,
       r.ThisStock StockToUse,
       r.RollingStock RunningTotal,
       s.TotalStock - r.RollingStock + r.ThisStock UseThisStock
FROM cteStockSum s INNER JOIN cteReverseInSum r
ON r.item_id = s.item_id AND r.RollingStock >= s.TotalStock
GROUP BY s.item_id;
```

The above query utilizes [SQLite's feature of bare columns](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query) to return the row of `cteReverseInSum` with the max date.